# make is not creating the kernel object file

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, kernel, kernel-module

I am modifying an existing kernel module SCTP. I've made it a loadable kernel module so that I can modify the module and test at runtime. The Makefile of the module is:

```
#
# Makefile for SCTP support code.
#

obj-$(CONFIG_IP_SCTP) += sctp.o
obj-$(CONFIG_NET_SCTPPROBE) += sctp_probe.o

sctp-y := sm_statetable.o sm_statefuns.o sm_sideeffect.o \
      protocol.o endpointola.o associola.o \
      transport.o chunk.o sm_make_chunk.o ulpevent.o \
      inqueue.o outqueue.o ulpqueue.o command.o \
      tsnmap.o bind_addr.o socket.o primitive.o \
      output.o input.o debug.o ssnmap.o auth.o

sctp_probe-y := probe.o

sctp-$(CONFIG_SCTP_DBG_OBJCNT) += objcnt.o
sctp-$(CONFIG_PROC_FS) += proc.o
sctp-$(CONFIG_SYSCTL) += sysctl.o

sctp-$(subst m,y,$(CONFIG_IPV6))    += ipv6.o
```

When I run make, it's creating 3 files `sctp_probe.o, sctp.o and modules.order`. But `sctp_probe.ko and sctp.ko` are not created by the above Makefile.

How to modify the above Makefile to create these two kernel object files?

**Updated with @vinay hunachyal's answer's else part.**

I tried with the method. after diagnosing some errors. Now I get this error at the end of the compilation of the kernel.

```
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/3.16.1/kernel/fs/dlm/dlm.ko needs unknown symbol sctp_do_peeloff
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 3.16.1 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/3.16.1/kernel/fs/dlm/dlm.ko needs unknown symbol sctp_do_peeloff
```

Comment: Update the question properly .. since error is during depmod not at compilation of module. so put some steps what you tried and error logs.?

Answer (score 1):

if you are building In kerenel tree source then in `menuconfig` you need to select Module in place of `Y` to `M`

`make menuconfig`

after this go to

`Networking support  --->`

inside here go to

`Networking options  --->`

if  its `y` change to `m`.

`{y} The SCTP Protocol  --->` change this to `{M} The SCTP Protocol  --->`

This will enables `sctp-y` to build as `dynamic module` instead of static.

after this go inside The SCTP Protocol

`<y>   SCTP: Association probing change to The SCTP Protocol`

This will enables `sctp_probe-y` to build as `dynamic module` instead of static.

At the end save and quit now you build

---

`ELSE` do following

If you are building outside kernel source-code tree.

copy net/sctp/ to outside kerenel source tree.

e.g cp net/sctp /home/vinay/dd/. -r

clean your kernel source tree.

`make clean`

`make dist clean`

then `make menuconfig`

`make modules_prepare`

in /home/vinay/dd/sctp/

in place of `KERNELDIR:= give path of configured kernel source tree`

e.g if kerenel source code in /home/vinay/linux-x.x.x

`KERNELDIR:=/home/vinay/linux-x.x.x`

**NOTE TAB should be exit after default and clean target .

Add below lines @ end of Makefile.

```
 KERNELDIR:=<path to configured kernel source tree >
 PWD:=$(shell pwd)

default:
 <tab> $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
 <tab> $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

This makes build simple

---

Comment: I'm doing the 1st step already. after the 1st build, I'm modifying few files of SCTP again and again to include my functions. Then what to do if i want to test the modified SCTP without rebuilding the whole kernel again and without rebooting?

Comment: have u tried 2nd one ?take complete code and build it instead of compiling whole kernel,here you can compile only sctp.

Comment: The 2nd one i'm unable to understand. how sctp module will work with out the dependent modules?

Comment: I tried it and  it worked for me.. in exiting makefile in sctp folder add below lines and compile it,Just u give a try and if any problem let me know

Comment: I tried the 2nd part and updated my question with the new error it's showing.

Comment: after trying the second method, the whole SCTP is missing from the kernel. i tried with `modprobe` and `insmod`. but both of them are saying no module found.

Comment: which kernel you running..? `uname -a ` gives present kernel running .. so check it which buiding module is same as running kernel

Comment: i'm running the latest 3.16.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59725/discussion-between-ratdon-and-vinay-hunachyal).

Comment: i'm running the latest 3.16.1.
somehow i made this to work.
i'm modifying the output.c file in sctp
then i'm running make inside sctp which is now creating the kernel object files.
now i'm trying to load the sctp module using modprobe sctp
but i'm unable to see my modification
i tried to unload the module using rmmod sctp. but it says that rmmod: ERROR: Module sctp is in use.
where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand kernel makefiles, these files will not be created as you have specifically asked the kernel make system to have the functionality as part of the Kernel monolith.

If you would replace the y with an m, you'd get kernel modules.

Like replace `sctp-y` with `sctp-m` and so on.

Comment: While building the kernel, i've selected the sctp as `M`. so it'd be a loadable kernel by default right? it should have replaced the `y`s with `m` on its own?

Comment: I've tried replacing them. the kernel is trying to build the kernel-object files but getting the following error instead.
`make[1]: *** No rule to make target `net/sctp/sctp_probe.c', needed by `net/sctp/sctp_probe.o'.  Stop.
make: *** [net/sctp/] Error 2`

Comment: I hope by sctp you meant IP_SCTP. In the Kconfig for sctp add the following:

config IP_SCTP
 tristate "The SCTP Protocol (EXPERIMENTAL)"
 depends on INET && EXPERIMENTAL
 depends on IPV6 || IPV6=n
 `depends on m`
It'll force it to compile as a module

Comment: no. SCTP is a separate module from 2.6 kernel onwards. (Experimental).

Comment: Sure but I am not talking about the name of the module. I'm talking about the config option. 

I've got a 2.6.34 here and the Kconfig file for net/sctp mentions:

`menuconfig IP_SCTP

 tristate "The SCTP Protocol (EXPERIMENTAL)"
`
So check your .config file with an editor to make sure `IP_SCTP` is getting built as a module. Like this:
`# CONFIG_IP_DCCP is not set [\n]
CONFIG_IP_SCTP=m [\n]
# CONFIG_SCTP_DBG_MSG is not set [\n]
`
The [\n] is only for demarcating a newline as SO doesn't allow newlines in comments it seems

Answer (score 0):

I am so sure your macros CONFIG_IP_SCTP and CONFIG_NET_SCTPPROBE dont have "m" value ,They are set to  "y".
You can verify these macros value in final .config file.
These macro should have defined like below

```
    CONFIG_NET_SCTPPROBE=m
    CONFIG_IP_SCTP=m
```

Thnaks

Comment: all are set to `m` only regarding SCTP in the `.config` except this one. `CONFIG_IP_VS_PROTO_SCTP=y`. i don't think we need to set this one to `m`